# Split dataframe column in R

Tags: r

I have a tibble

```
a <- tribble(~names,"|david:123|",)
```

and I've seen code that does the following but, not sure what it does.

```
a %>% split(.$names)
```

Comment: @RonakShah sorry, im not sure I follow. The code snippet is a full example. Im just not sure of what the .$ does and which character we're splitting on.

Answer (score 0):

`split` splits the dataframe based on values in a column. You have provided one row data which is not helpful to demonstrate what it does. Let's consider the inbuilt `mtcars` dataset.

The unique values in `cyl` column of `mtcars` dataset are 6, 4, 8.

```
unique(mtcars$cyl)
#[1] 6 4 8
```

When we use `mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)` it divides `mtcars` dataset into list of length 3 where each list consists of one unique `cyl` value.

```
temp <- mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)
temp[[1]]
#                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#...


temp[[2]]
#                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#...

temp[[3]]
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#...
```

As we can see that `mtcars[[1]]` has all the rows where `cyl = 4`, `mtcars[[2]]` has rows where `cyl = 6`, `mtcars[[3]]` has all `cyl = 8`.

Similarly, for your case, `a %>% split(.$names)` splits dataframe/tibble  into list of unique `names` from the data. `.$names` is to extract the `names` column from `a` dataframe.